# tomcat and springMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

Like the tutorial, I deployed the tomcat server step by step, and then used postman to test the back-end login function interface, but kept reporting errors, and at the end of the terminal it printed out :

```
Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool. BasicResourcePool@2bda742d is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
```

The complete output in the terminal in idea is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eslgi.png)

the error on postman show that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEXbZ.png)

it was just download all the time and have no result, and I can ensure the url is right.
I will appreciate it if you can answer me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the password of the database root account was wrong, maybe you should check your configuration file.

Comment: Oh, You got it bro.

Comment: My configuration were wrong and it was means that my sql's password was wrong, thanks my brother.